# C# Linq database gridview code issue "cannot assign implicitly-typed local variable"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, linq

what is this error? How do I solve this?

[The screenshot of the code snippet and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EslI6.jpg)

**Here is the code**

```
namespace School_Management_System
{
    public partial class Roles : Dashboard2
    {
        public Roles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int edit = 0;
        myDBDataContext obj = new myDBDataContext(); //datacontext class

        private void Roles_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainClass.disable_reset(panel6);
            var view = obj.staff_getRoles();

                roleIDGV.DataPropertyName = "ID";
                roleGV.DataPropertyName = "Role";
                statusGV.DataPropertyName = "Status";
                dataGridView1.DataSource = view;

        }
```

This is my database code for retrieving the data and show in the system. 
create procedure staff_getRoles as select r.role_id as 'ID', r.role_name as 'Role' , case when (r.role_status = 1) then 'Active' else 'In-active' end as 'Status' from roles r

Answer (score 0):

By the errormessige, it sounds like `obj.staff_getRoles();` has returntype `void`.
[image: d]

Comment: This is my code in database to get the data from database to the system datagrideview.

create procedure staff_getRoles
as
select r.role_id as 'ID', r.role_name as 'Role' ,
case when (r.role_status = 1) then 'Active' else 'In-active' end as 'Status'
from roles r

Comment: But the linked screen-shot on the top of your post tells same error-message - "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable".

Comment: First you need to check if this is the case. What is the returnvalue of the ´stuff_getRoles()´? If it has a returntype of ´void´, it does not do what you expect it to do. Maybe there are another method you can call or the correct db interface method yet needs to be implemented.